# How to simultaneously retrieve many pieces of information from an API?

Tags: json, r, api

I'm very new to interacting with APIs so I apologize in advance if this question is particularly stupid.

I'm trying to retrieve all of the drug interaction information from ONCHigh from the RxNav Drug Interaction RESTful API in JSON format to analyze using R. However, as far as I can tell, the API is set up such that you have to retrieve information about each drug interaction individually by including the RxCUI in the URI to access the web service.

This is what I currently have, after "rxcui=" is where I'm assuming this problem could potentially be fixed... if it can at all.

```
DIAPI <- 
fromJSON("https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/interaction/interaction.json?
rxcui=&sources=ONCHigh")
```

Comment: That's pretty much how most APIs work. Often times you would set up a loop to retrieve data from multiple URLs if the server you are getting the data from doesn't have a different endpoint to retrieve more than on record at a time.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I'll do